# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Chrome Dev Tools to indent a block of code?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Chrome Dev Tools to indent a block of code?

I'm used to using **Command + ]** in Coda 2, but that only switches panes in Chrome Dev Tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highlighting the code (whether one or multiple lines) and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> is indenting all the lines with highlight for me. Hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will un-indent the highlighted lines.

The whole line does not need to be highlighted, just at least one character on the line.

Comment: Well there you have it! *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, there are other shortcuts you can use in the DevTools editor which are documented here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#code-editor